# Die robusten und festen Beziehungen zu den USA würden aber in „keiner Weise“ betrübt

Tags: grammar-identification

The paragraph is in the book. [link](https://bit.ly/2GEPmLK)

> Der Regierungssprecher bedauerte die Veröffentlichung. Die Dokumente seien „auf illegale Art und Weise an die
>   Öffentlichkeit gelangt“. Die robusten und festen Beziehungen zu den USA würden aber in „keiner Weise“ betrübt.
>   Es gebe eine in Jahrzehnten gewachsene tiefe Freundschaft, die auf gemeinsamen Werten beruhe und durch die
>   Publikation „nicht ernsthaft beschädigt wird“. Passagen über deutsche Politiker hätten eher das „Niveau des
>   Lästerns“.

My question is about the sentence:

> Die robusten und festen Beziehungen zu den USA **würden** aber in „keiner Weise“ **betrübt**.

Normally I see " würde + infinitive present (simple würde-form) or würde + infinitive perfect (würde-perfect)" structure in the subjunctive II form, though in the above sentence  würden seems to precede adjective "betrübt" so I would like to know whether the structure is fine or I am missing something.

Comment: Since the link does not work for me: Are you sure, it is *betrübt*? I would have written and expected *getrübt*. Something as abstract as "friendship" is difficult to make sad….

Comment: @guidot see if this is working. [link] (https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ci8lDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=%E2%80%9C.+Die+robusten+und+festen+Beziehungen+zu+den+USA+w%C3%BCrden+aber+in+%E2%80%9Ekeiner+Weise%E2%80%9C+betr%C3%BCbt.&source=bl&ots=aWQDY7Lyrq&sig=ACfU3U3wVhXh4XfV-mEvVIvLwfw4allUdg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM4aGfoenhAhUIfH0KHVJ8BGEQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9C.%20Die%20robusten%20und%20festen%20Beziehungen%20zu%20den%20USA%20w%C3%BCrden%20aber%20in%20%E2%80%9Ekeiner%20Weise%E2%80%9C%20betr%C3%BCbt.&f=false)

Comment: @guidot, in der Quelle steht "betrübt", ich hätte aber auch "getrübt" erwartet.

Comment: @Iris Es geht hier eben nicht um das Verb _trüben_, sondern um _betrüben_.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich, das ist mir klar, aber kann "eine Beziehung betrüben"? Ich kann jemanden betrüben, aber kann ich etwas betrüben?

Comment: @Iris In dem Beispiel ist es meines Erachtens nicht die Beziehung, die betrübt (Aktiv), sondern sie selbst wird (von jemandem) betrübt (Passiv).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, es gibt immerhin ein Beispiel von "betrübten Kriegszeiten" (https://www.dwds.de/wb/betr%C3%BCben). Wenn Kriegszeiten betrüben können, können es Beziehungen wohl auch, seltsam klingt es in meinen Ohren trotzdem.

Comment: Es **könnte** natürlich auch ein nicht entdeckter Schreibfehler sein.

Answer (score 4):

This is the *Konjunktiv II* mood of *werden* used as a **full verb**. It's used as a copula and *betrübt* is a predicative. The *Partizip II* is used as an adjective here.

> Die Beziehungen werden dadurch nicht betrübt. *(Indikativ)*
>
> Die Beziehungen würden dadurch nicht betrübt. *(Konjunktiv II)*

This seems hard to identify. I recommend to keep in mind the tenses/voices/aspects using *sein* and *werden* have this kind of *copula Doppelgänger*. The good message is that Doppelgänger means exactly the same – it's just another view on the grammar.

Also, *bleiben* and the *als-verbs* (*sehen als*, *gelten als* etc.) are used similarily and you may draw a line from those to the two kinds of passive voice (using either *sein+Partizip II* or *werden+Partizip II*) German has. It's all talking about the properties of an item.

Comment: Was sagst Du zu guidots Anmerkung, es müsse "getrübt" heißen?

Comment: @userunknown _Trüben_ und _betrüben_ sind zwei verschiedene Verben. Warum also sollte der Verfasser _getrübt_ schreiben, wenn er _betrübt_ meint?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich   Ich glaube nicht, dass der Verfasser *betrübt* gemeint hat. Er hat sich einfach vertan bei der Wortwahl. Hätte er drüber nachgedacht, wäre er draufgekommen, dass Beziehungen nach aller existierenden Sprachpraxis ***getrübt*** werden, und dass die Beteiligten darüber dann ***betrübt*** sein können. Man muss nicht jedes Wort glauben, nur weil es gedruckt wurde. Nicht zuletzt: Die Leute *lügen wie **gedruckt*** (und nicht etwa *wie **bedruckt***.)

Comment: Würde da *getrübt* stehen, wäre es naheliegend, von einem Vorgangspassiv des Verbs *trüben* auszugehen. **Es steht da aber nicht.** – Das Verb *betrüben* im Vorgangspassiv kommt mir arg seltsam vor. Wer verwendet bitte dieses Verb überhaupt als Verb? Mir ist nur die Verwendung als Partizip/Adjektiv geläufig. Daher auch meine Antwort. Von der Bedeutung her ist es ohnehin mit dem Vorgangspassiv identisch.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich glaube, dass _betrüben_ in dem Satz _„Die Beziehungen wurden betrübt.“_ anders gemeint ist, und zwar analog zu anderen, seltenen Verben mit der Vorsilbe _be-_, die im Passiv verwendet werden. Beispiel: _„Der Rasen wurde beregnet.“_ Der Satz klingt ungewohnt, ist aber korrekt. Daraus _„Der Rasen wurde geregnet.“_ (immer noch Passiv) oder _„Der Rasen hat geregnet.“_ (Aktiv) zu machen, wäre falsch. _Betrüben_ ist hier meines Erachtens im Sinne von _etwas trübe machen_ gemeint, und nicht im Sinne von _trautig werden_.

Comment: Das ist aber genau der Unterschied zwischen den Verben trüben/betrüben und regnen/beregnen. Das Verb *regnen* ist **intransitiv**, *beregnen* die transitive Variante. Für *trüben* gilt dies jedoch nicht, denn *trüben* ist bereits transitiv. Das Verb *betrüben* ist eigentlich überflüssig.

Comment: @Janke Das gilt auch für _schenken/beschenken_ und vermutlich auch für andere Verben. Falsch ist es trotzdem nicht.

Comment: Das Verb *schenken* funktioniert wieder anders, weil das Akkusativobjekt von *schenken* und *beschenken* etwas anderes bedeutet.

Answer (score 3):

## *Trüben, betrübt, betrüben*

As guidot surmised in a comment, there is a mistake in the sentence you quoted: *betrübt* should be *getrübt*. A slightly modified version of the sentence in question would be:

> Die Beziehungen zu den USA **würden** durch die Veröffentlichung der Dokumente nicht **getrübt**.

*Würden… getrübt* is **Konjunktiv II Passiv** of **trüben**. Note that *würden… getrübt werden* is also possible (see below). Konjunktiv II is used instead of Konjunktiv I because the latter is identical to the indicative in the plural. The purpose of the Konjunktiv is to indicate that the sentence is to be understood as reported speech, i.e. the spokesperson must have said,

> Die Beziehungen zu den USA **werden** durch die Veröffentlichung der Dokumente nicht **getrübt**.

or, in the active,

> Die Veröffentlichung der Dokumente **trübt** die Beziehungen zu den USA nicht.

The literal meaning of *trüben* is to make something opaque. The figurative meaning is like that of English *to tarnish*, to make worse, which fits perfectly.

**Betrübt** is another kettle of fish. It is a deverbal adjective indicating sadness.

> Der Regierungssprecher war betrübt.
>   Er zeigte sich betrübt.
>   Wenn sie an den Klimawandel denkt, wird sie ganz betrübt.
>   Ihre Miene war betrübt.

As the examples indicate, the adjective *betrübt* requires a person as a subject (or a bodypart metonymically denoting a person). *Beziehungen* is not a valid subject here, and the meaning doesn't fit either because *Beziehungen* can't get sad.

Finally, there is also the transitive verb **betrüben**, which means *to make sad*:

> Die Situation betrübt mich zutiefst.
>   Der Gedanke betrübt uns alle.

Again, since the object is required to denote a person, *Beziehungen* cannot possibly be the subject of a passive sentence with *betrüben*, and the meaning is off as well (*Beziehungen* can't get sad).

## *würde* plus infinitive

As you are already aware, *würde* plus infinitive is used in place of Konjunktiv II in certain cases.

> Die Beziehungen **verschlechtern** sich. →
>   Die Beziehungen **verschlechterten** sich. *(ambiguous, could be past indicative)*
>   Die Beziehungen **würden** sich **verschlechtern**.

This is called the periphrastic Konjunktiv II, *periphrastic* meaning that two verbs combine in order to express a grammatical feature.

However, what about the Konjunktiv II of *werden* itself, when *werden* is used as a passive auxiliary or a copula? There are two possibilities: Either *würde* is used to form a Konjunktiv II on its own, or it is combined with another *werden* in order to form a periphrastic Konjunktiv II (so that there are two forms of *werden* present). The latter use is considered more colloquial.

> Die Probleme **werden** von einigen vernachlässigt. →
>   Die Probleme **würden** von einigen vernachlässigt.
>   Die Probleme **würden** von einigen vernachlässigt **werden**.
>
> Die Probleme **werden** jeden Tag größer. →
>   Die Probleme **würden** jeden Tag größer.
>   Die Probleme **würden** jeden Tag größer **werden**.

Comment: Since OP expected some form of "würden" + infinitive, it might be useful to point out that the form that most closely corresponds to their expectation is "würden betrübt werden", but that Konjunktiv II is (at least in higher registered) preferrably (if possible) not expressed by the paraphrastic form (würde + Infinitive) but by the simple conjunctive form of the verb.

Comment: @DavidVogt lately I found this sentence. Will it fall under "würde + adjective" structure?
- Was würden wir sagen, wenn die Gletscher immer **größer** und die Eiskappen am Süd- und Nordpol immer **dicker** **würden**?

Comment: @ughitudhi I wouldn't call it a structure. There are 4 different kinds of *werden*: 1) future auxiliary *Wir werden Sie benachrichtigen*, 2) passive auxiliary *Sie werden von uns benachrichtigt*, 3) copula *Die Probleme werden größer* and 4) subjunctive auxiliary *Ich würde gern mitkommen*. *Werden* in 2) and 3) can appear in the subjunctive, just as in your example.

Comment: @DavidVogt Thank you very much